# Remote Debugging in Azure Container Apps

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger, azure-container-apps

I will have 50-60 microservices each built as asp.net web API, all running within a single Azure Container Apps environment, each able to synchronously communicate with each other via DAPR.

Is it possible to attach (via VS Code or VS) a debugger such that I can debug through the code on any of these services running within Azure Container Apps?

Answer (score 0):

Remote debugging is currently not available with Azure Container Apps. One workaround to this could be to view the log streams for your deployed Container Apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/log-streaming?tabs=bash

You can use the AZ CLI to achieve this:

```
az containerapp logs show --name <container-app-name> --resource-group <rg-name> --tail
```

There are more parameters you can pass in, described in this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/logs?view=azure-cli-latest

The console logs will stream logs from your container console. The system logs will stream logs from the Container Apps service itself. This include Dapr logs such as components being created, updated or failed to be created. You can read more about the difference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/sr-Cyrl-RS/azure/container-apps/logging

This isn't the most elegant way of debugging (you'll probably have to leg checkpoints in the code to see where the code fails), but it's a workaround for now.

Answer (score -1):

In ***VS 2022***, I tried to Configure and Attach remote debugger for Azure Container Apps.

Please check the below Workaround.

- Created `ASP.Net Web API` and Enabled docker.

[image]

- Published the Web App to Azure Container App.
- In ***VS*** => ***Debug*** => ***Attach to Process***, tried to connect to the remote , got the below error.

[image]

Thanks to @[ryanchill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/374384/how-to-remote-debugging-net-5-docker-container-app.html), as mentioned, Remote Debugging for Azure Container Apps is not supported as of now.

Comment: How is this supposed to be an answer? The comment from ryanchill is more than one year old, I did not find any information about VS2022 though. But even if it was supported, I would assume you'd need more configuration than just enable Docker on the project.